# Pythonでディレクトリ内部のファイルを上書きせずに、存在しないファイルだけコピーしたい

Tags: python, windows

以下のようなディレクトリ構造があります。

```
testFolderA
    |_ copyfolder
        |_ aaa.txt
        |_ bbb.txt
        |_ ccc.txt
        |_ ddd.txt
        |_ eee.txt
testFolderB
    |_ copyfolder
        |_ aaa.txt
        |_ ccc.txt
        |_ eee.txt
```

Pythonで、copyfolderをディレクトリごとtestFolderAからtestFolderBにコピーしたいです。
その際に、すでにあるファイルは上書きしないようにしたいです。

この例の場合だと、aaa.txtとccc.txtとeee.txtは既にあるのでコピーをせずに
bbb.txtとddd.txtだけコピーしたいです。

以下のコマンドを実行したところ、エラーになってコピーできません。

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree('testFolderA/copyfolder','testFolderB/copyfolder')
```

どのようなコードでコピーするのが効率的でしょうか？

さらに下位ディレクトリがある場合も、再帰的に処理を行い、すべてのファイルを走査し、ないものはコピー、あるものは保留をしたいです。コピー先にディレクトリがない場合はディレクトリも作成されていてほしいです。

Windows環境を想定しています。

Comment: さらに下位ディレクトリがある時どうなってほしいとか、実行環境 (Windows / Linux / その他) であるとか、コピーすることが目的であるなら [tag:python] でなくてもよいのかとかを、追記していただくとよい提案が出るでしょう。

Comment: 同じファイル名で内容に差がある場合もコピーは不要なのでしょうか？

Comment: はい。コピー先で同じファイル名のファイルが同じフォルダ名の中に入っている場合、ファイルの中身が違ってもコピー不要です。

Comment: 外部コマンドで良いならFastCopyというツールが使えそうです。[サイズの大きいファイルでも、高速にコピーすることができる！「FastCopy」。](https://www.gigafree.net/utility/move/fastcopy.html), [7. コマンドラインモード](https://fastcopy.jp/help/fastcopy.htm#cmdline) があって、`差分（上書きなし）　同じファイル名がある場合、コピーしません。`というモードが指定出来るようです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python 3.8 で[`shutil.copytree`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree)の引数に`dirs_exist_ok`が追加されました。
`dirs_exist_ok=True`を指定することでエラーが発生しなくなります。

ただしこの状態ではすべてのファイルを上書きしてしまうため、`ignore`引数を使用することで存在しないファイルのみコピーすることができます。
実際のコードは下記のサンプルコードを参考にしてください。

**サンプルコード**

```
import shutil
import os

def ignore(d, l):
    retVal = [] # 存在しないファイルのリスト
    for p in l:
        # isfile ではなく exists を使うとフォルダを再帰的にコピーしてくれないので注意
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dst, p)): # ignore(d, l)のdはコピー元のパスなので、dstを使わないとコピー先の存在チェックができない
            retVal.append(p)
    # 存在しないファイルを無視リストとして戻す
    return retVal

src = 'testFolderA/copyfolder'
dst = 'testFolderB/copyfolder'
# dirs_exist_okは3.8以降使用可能
shutil.copytree(src, dst, ignore=ignore, dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

Windows限定ならば`Process`からrobocopyなどのコマンドを呼び出す方法も考えられますが、この回答には含みません。

Answer (score 1):

> Pythonで、copyfolderをディレクトリごとtestFolderAからtestFolderBにコピーしたいです。
> その際に、すでにあるファイルは上書きしないようにしたいです。
> どのようなコードでコピーするのが効率的でしょうか？

効率的というか, コピーする際に `testFolderB`のディレクトリー構造が破壊されてしまうので
(個人的には)非破壊的な手順にするでしょう … target: 第 3のディレクトリーを用意し

1. `testFolderA` から targetへすべてコピー
2. `testFolderB` から targetへ上書きコピー

のような手順。
他には, ファイルやディレクトリー管理を行うのが目的なら [アーカイブ](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/archiving.html) を利用するかも

- [zipfile --- ZIP アーカイブの処理](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/zipfile.html)
- [tarfile --- tar アーカイブファイルの読み書き](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/tarfile.html)

(tar アーカイバーに馴染みがなく, zipしか使ったこと無いなら zip 一択になるけど)

---

`shutil.copytree`を利用する場合:

> さらに下位ディレクトリがある場合も、再帰的に処理を行い、すべてのファイルを走査し、ないものはコピー、あるものは保留をしたいです。コピー先にディレクトリがない場合はディレクトリも作成されていてほしいです。

```py
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

def f_exists(base, dst):
    base, dst = Path(base), Path(dst)
    def _ignore(path, names):   # サブディレクトリー毎に呼び出される
        names = set(names)
        rel = Path(path).relative_to(base)
        return {f.name for f in (dst/ rel).glob('*') if f.name in names}
    return _ignore

src = 'testFolderA/copyfolder'
dst = 'testFolderB/copyfolder'
shutil.copytree(src, dst, ignore=f_exists(src, dst), dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: 関数名が `not_exists` では `ignote=` で指定するのに逆の意味になるので, 関数名変えました